# Guest on Mac host still has tiny screen after installing Virtual Box Guest Additions

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I ran the following command as per *"[Unable to Install Guest Additions CD Image on Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box)"*, restarted the server, and it still behaves like the guest utils haven't been installed, because I'm still getting the tiny screen. Electing to make the clipboard and drag 'n' drop functionality bidirectional (via the Devices menu item) appears to do nothing as well. Any suggestions?

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: Was the installation of `virtualbox-guest-utils` successful? If not, repeat the installation command and post its output?

Comment: David Foerster - Yes, the install was successful. I removed it. Then, successfully added again. But still no luck. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 error messages. Then found this. Did the three steps, restarted and the screen is perfect.

I did `sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23`, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` and finally `sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11` . It solved problems for me.