# Unable to insert the virtual optical disk (VBoxguestaddition) in virtual machine for ubuntu server in win 10

Tags: boot, server, mount, virtualbox, guest-additions

I am new in this kind of environment and I want to learn this. This is  started once I install VirtualBox-5.2.18-124319-Win and successfully installing ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64 in that virtual machine, however in the instruction command me to install VBoxguestaddition, and I get this kind of error, eventhough I have 2 installations of VBoxguestaddition and VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.20 in .iso;

```
Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: 
IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
```

I tried use sudo command in terminal `sudo mount /dev/cdrom/media/cdrom` and not succeed, I ask my friend and lecturer but no one give a proper advice. Thank you in advance. [image: screen shoot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Install Guest Additions CD Image on Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box)

Answer (score 8):

Fooling around with this problem, I clicked on Devices>Optical Drives and unchecked VBoxGuestAdditions.iso.

I then got a question asking: Would you like to try to force ejection of this disk? I clicked the [Force Unmount] box.

Next, go back to Devices>Optical Drives and add a check tp the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

At least I'm no longer getting an error. Hope this works for you

Comment: This worked for me. Though it's kinda weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I went to

> Devices -> Optical Drives

and selected "Remove Disk From Virtual Drive". Then "Force Unmount".
Then I was able to select

> Devices -> Install Guest Additions CD Image...

Comment: where exactly is Devices ?

Answer (score 1):

I just started using Ubuntu and came across this problem. When you get this error, it will show that the file(with its path) could not be loaded. You have a good look at it and maybe write it down somewhere.Now, you should look at the bottom right of your virtual machine window, you will see a CD Icon thingy. Right click on it and select "Choose a disk file". Click there and navigate with that path to the iso file. Click on it and a window will pop up, select 'Force Unmount'(weird thing the file infact loads). Now, right click on CD Icon again and you should see VBox something something.iso , click on it and a window will popup in Ubuntu, click run and enter your password. Done

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error `This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules` open the terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install gcc perl make`. Then reboot, right click the guest addition cd and unmount it, and then re-insert it from Devices in menu.

Answer (score 0):

This in the VirtualBox, is a bit of pain always. However, for me, it worked like this:

Under devices, unmount & remount the Guest ISO. For me a window opened where all the necessary Tetris packages were now included. They weren't included in the VM folder. I went to the folder on the system (Parrot in this case) and just run the autoinstal.sh with sudo ./autoinstal.sh. It installed now smoothly and now the full screen is working.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid one mistake which I made.
Make sure you have logged in to the system before following the steps mentioned above.