# How do I make Ubuntu Linux full screen in Oracle Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, oracle

I have installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine by following [this article](https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-in-virtualbox/.).
I called the VM "myLinux", I succeeded to install it, but linux is not in full screen.

I made some searches and tried to fix it by Insert Guest Editions CD image, but it gave me an error:

> Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine myLinux2.
> Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Component: ConsoleWrap
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
> Callee: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}

I tried [Remove disk from virtual drive from the Optical Drives menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box), but it didn't help.
Please help, it's really frustrating.

Comment: Start with https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: Also  https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box