# Guest additions stopped working in VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box). Nothing from answers helped. I tried http://youtu.be/5_fluJuJc6E?t=58 but Remove Attachment is grayed out. I have VirtualBox 6.1 and Lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. Actually, this is `Lubuntu`. You probably remembered another question, where I installed Ubuntu with LXDE to my coworker. This is another case. Lubuntu 18.04 in virtual machine where I run mainly apache. Do you recommend me some upgrade? I don't know the shortest command sequence for upgrade to newer version. :-) so I'm not upgrading so far.

Comment: I'm not sure I recommended anyone installing Lubuntu 18.04 LTS unless the box was *i386* or 32-bit as it was the end of the road (technically 18.10 & 19.04 were supported for *i386* but ended life before 18.04 LTS did/does). Lubuntu 18.04 LTS being the end of the road for upgrades; other *flavors* usually made more sense, unless the user was capable enough to fix their own issues.   (*I don't usually remember many users, as I see 30-80 support questions per day; unless it's the same identical question asked on multiple sites; those stand out*)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415716/kubuntu-14-04-to-full-screen-via-virtual-box) answer helped.

```
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.26.iso /mnt
```

and

```
sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```